# List<Object> variable being assignment compatible with other generic Lists like List<String> in Java

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

I've been trying to get my head around java generics for the last few days. From what I understand, Java generics are not covariant so `List<Object>` is not assignment compatible with other generics `List`s

But here in the following program, `nameAndPhone.collect()` method returns a List of type `List<NamePhone>` and when I replace reference variable `List<NamePhone> npList` with `List<Object> npList` the program still compiles without warnings.

I tried this with a similar method returning `List<String>` as well, and using `List<Object>` reference variable did not result in any error.

Why is `List<Object>` assignment compatible with `List<NamePhone>` here?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class NamePhoneEmail
{
    String name;
    String phonenum;
    String email;

    NamePhoneEmail(String n, String p, String e)
    {
        name = n;
        phonenum = p;
        email = e;
    }
}

class NamePhone
{
    String name;
    String phonenum;

    NamePhone(String n, String p)
    {
        name = n;
        phonenum = p;
    }
}

public class CollectDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ArrayList<NamePhoneEmail> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(
            new NamePhoneEmail("Larry", "555-5555", "Larry@HerbSchildt.com"));

        myList.add(
            new NamePhoneEmail("James", "555-4444", "James@HerbSchildt.com"));

        Stream<NamePhone> nameAndPhone =
            myList.stream().map((a) -> new NamePhone(a.name, a.phonenum));

        List<NamePhone> npList = nameAndPhone.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see `List<Object>` anywhere

Comment: There is no `List<Object>` to be seen in your example code.  Do you mean that you can change npList type from `List<NamePhone>` to `List<Object>` and it works? In that case there is a explanation but you need to change your code example or text around it to reflect that

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I mean replacing List<NamePhone> npList = nameAndPhone.collect(Collectors.toList()); with List<Object> npList = nameAndPhone.collect(Collectors.toList()); doesn't result in Type mismatch error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that the types are **not** assignment compatible.

In doubt, this can easily be verified:

```
List<Object> a = null;
List<NamePhone> b = null;
a = b;                      // Error!
```

---

The reason of why it **seems** to be assignment compatible in this case is the [target type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types). The inference process can be complicated - particularly in this case, which involves a `Collector`, which has *three* type parameters.

I'll try to flesh out the relevant parts here:

The signature of the `collect` method is as follows:

```
<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector);
```

This is called on the `Stream<T>` instance. In your case, this is a `Stream<NamePhone>`. But note that *the method itself* has additional generic parameters, namely `R` and `A`. The relevant one here is `R`, which is the *return type*.

The `Collector` that is passed in there is the one created by the `toList` method, which looks as follows:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList()
```

It is also generic. The type parameter will basically be "substituted", based on the *context* in which the method is called.

So when you write this:

```
List<NamePhone> npList = nameAndPhone.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then you will have the following type assignments:

1. The `T` of the `Stream` is `NamePhone`
2. The `T` of the `Collector` is `NamePhone`
3. The `R` of the `collect` method is `List<NamePhone>`

But you could also write

```
List<Object> npList = nameAndPhone.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this case

1. The `T` of the `Stream` is `NamePhone`
2. The `T` of the `Collector` is `Object`
3. The `R` of the `collect` method is `List<Object>`

Note that this is only possible because the `collect` method accepts a `Collector<? super T, ...>`. It would not work if it expected a `Collector<T, ...>`. This basically means that you can use the elements from the `Stream` and collect them into a new `List`, as long as the type parameter of the desired list is a *supertype* of the elements in the stream.

---

Conceptually, this makes sense, because it's in some way analogous to

```
List<Integer> integers = ...;
List<Number> numbers = ...;
for (Integer i : integers) numbers.add(i); // This should work as well!
```

Comment: So the type of the Collector gets inferred from the target variables type List<Object>? Not from the invoking Streams type i.e Stream<NamePhone>?

Comment: @Arjun Yes, basically. This is shown in a simpler example in the [link that I posted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types), where the *target type* of `T`in `static <T> List<T> emptyList();` is inferred to be `String`, depending on the type of the variable that the result is assigned to.

Answer (score 8):

The type parameter of what gets returned by [the `collect` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) does not need to be the same type as the stream.  Here, the result type `R` is different than the stream type `T`.

> ```
> <R,A> R collect​(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)
> ```

Next, Java 8 and later have improved target type inference.  That means that the compiler will use the target type to infer type parameters.  In this case, when you have

```
List<NamePhone> npList = nameAndPhone.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the compiler sees `NamePhone` and infers that type as the type parameter `R` to `collect` (and to `Collectors.toList()`).

When you change it to

```
List<Object> npList = nameAndPhone.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the compiler sees `Object` and infers that type as the type parameter `R`.

This compiles and works as expected, because you can certainly place any kind of object, including a `NamePhone`, into a `List<Object>`.

It's not that a `List<NamePhone>` is assignment compatible with `List<Object>`.  What is happening is that when you say `List<Object> npList`, there never was a `List<NamePhone>`, only a `List<Object>`.

Note that the objects in your list will have a runtime type of `NamePhone` in either case.

Comment: The fact that type parameters are "local to their context" (and e.g. a type variable `T` may virtually appear multiple times in one expression) makes things complicated here: The type `R` is in fact not `NamePhone`, but `List<NamePhone>`. Other than that, the description is likely easier to understand than mine, +1...